# Inspection to separate one java package from the rest of the project

Tags: java, code-inspection

I have a java package `foo.bar`. It contains few classes, that are frequently modified, improved etc in this time of project.

I don't want any developer to use classes from the other packages in this one. I want this package to be separated in its usage. So this package must be isolated.

I could make an external jar, but that would introduce much more handling for little number of classes, that it does not make sense.

I want this inspection to be run from my build process.

I tried several code-inspection tools (pmd...) but I was not able to configure this. How to do this?

Comment: Why don't you just use a build tool which can handle that for you? Just create a separate module for this package and make it depend on nothing but the JDK

Comment: Let's just say that it's not simple as that.